# Parameters for filter, cleaner way?

Tags: filter, web.xml, param

I'm writing a filter and want to exclude some directories from that filter.
Right now i've got this:

```
 <filter>
        <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>filter.aFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>excludePatterns</param-name>
            <param-value>/css,/images</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
```

I was wondering if there is a cleaner way than the comma seperated values, which I have to split in my filter. Is there a pure xml way of specifying multiple parameters in the web.xml file for your filter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10111406/1700321

Comment: That one is about context-param, is it the same for init-param?